# Invalid column name when multiplying aliases

Tags: sql-server

I have these two tables:

- Cart_Details (Cart_ID, Product_ID, Quantity, Subtotal)
- Products (Product_ID, Name, Description)

My SQL statement:

```
SELECT TOP 5 
    t1.Product_ID, 
    t1.Name,
    t1.Category,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM Cart_Details
     WHERE Cart_Details.Product_ID = t1.Product_ID) AmountSold,
    (SELECT Quantity 
     FROM Cart_Details 
     WHERE t1.Product_ID = Cart_Details.Product_ID) AS Quantity,
    (Quantity * AmountSold) AS FinalSold
FROM 
    [dbo].[Product] t1
```

I'm trying to multiply value from aliases (`AmountSold` and `Quantity`) and have the result as `FinalSold`, but I get errors:

> Invalid column name 'AmountSold'.

and

> Invalid column name 'Quantity'.

Is there other way for me to have the value from the both aliases added into a new column?

Comment: You can't reference an alias at the same scope. You can repeat the expression or nest using CTEs/subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

One method to use calculated fields is to wrap it in a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (Quantity*AmountSold)AS FinalSold
FROM (SELECT top 5 
         t1.Product_ID, 
         t1.Name,
         t1.Category,
         (select count(*) 
          from Cart_Details
          where Cart_Details.Product_ID=t1.Product_ID ) AmountSold,
         (select Quantity 
          from Cart_Details 
          where t1.Product_ID=Cart_Details.Product_ID) AS Quantity,
    FROM [dbo].[Product] t1) AS InnerTable
```

Answer (score 0):

A alternative is to use CTE:

```
;WITH CTEQuery AS 
 (SELECT  
         t1.Product_ID, 
         t1.Name,
         t1.Category,
        (select count(*) 
         from   Cart_Details
         where  Cart_Details.Product_ID = t1.Product_ID) AmountSold,
        (select Quantity 
         from   Cart_Details 
         where  t1.Product_ID=Cart_Details.Product_ID) AS Quantity             
   FROM [dbo].[Product] t1)

SELECT  top 5 (Quantity*AmountSold) AS FinalSold, *
FROM    CTEQuery
```